# Reducing Standard Salesforce User License for users with minimal need

Tags: community, user, licenses, userlicense

In our org we have some users who are using only a few custom objects.These users need access to either create or edit records from these objects.

Since these users have very minimal need for a Standard Salesforce User License our clients are asking if there is any other way to access these custom objects without the Standard Salesforce User License.

As soon as this requirement came, i thought about Community logins, where we can give them access to some of the custom objects(but looks like this also needs some Community login licenses)

Is there any other way where we can achieve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is the customer looking to reduce the cost of access for these users? If so, a digital experience with customer users (Community licenses) may be the most cost effective from the access perspective, though it does have other costs such the development effort of the digital experience, any necessary sharing setup etc.

An alternative, assuming CRM features are not required, is to use Salesforce Platform licenses instead of Salesforce licenses. Due to the CRM restrictions, these are less expensive.

It might be worth talking to your Salesforce account manager.